# Sending JSON from AS3 to PHP

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3, variables

I really can't figure out what's wrong.

Im sending JSON from AS3 to PHP:

```
var sendToPHPJson:String = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(sqlResult);

myRequest = new URLRequest("http://xxx.pl/FlashFiles/Winebook/uploadToServer.php");
myLoader = new URLLoader;
myVariables = new URLVariables;
myVariables.firstProperty = sendToPHPJson;
myLoader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE,onUploadingComplete);
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myRequest.data = myVariables;
myLoader.load(myRequest);
```

And my PHP is receiving:

```
<?php
include "XXX.php";
$json=$_POST['firstProperty'];
$data = json_decode($json);
$answe=$data[0]->wineName;
echo "answer='".$answe."'";
?>
```

And i receive answer=''. But when I hardcode sendToPHPJson into PHP answer has good value.

What can be wrong? What to change?

*EDIT:
I did some search and rebuild code to:

AS3:

```
var url:String = "http://adres/uploadToServer.php";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.myObject = sendToPHPJson;
request.data = requestVars;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE,onUploadingComplete);
loader.load(request);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include "XXX.php";
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST['myObject']);
print_r($_POST);
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$wynik = json_decode($content);
echo $wynik;
?>
```

And I still get no data in:

```
private function onUploadingComplete(e:flash.events.Event):void
{
    trace("upload complete");
    trace(e.target.data);
    txtField.text = String(e.target.data);
    this.touchable = true;
}
```

Comment: Did you found the solution? If yes, then please post.

Comment: The bad thing was that PHP received wrong formated JSON due to compiler adding "\" sign before special signs. I've used **json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myObject']));** on receiving JSON in PHP and all began to work fine :) See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943488/json-format-lost-in-php

Comment: Yes i did the same 1 hour before and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
myRequest.data = myVariables;
```

Also, AS3 has built-in JSON top level class, no need to use 3rd party libraries. Next time check var_dump($_POST) or browser network info, how's your data is being sent.

Comment: Just for reference sake, [here is the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) for the JSON class you spoke of, although I believe the class he used for it was a precursor to the current top-level class.

Comment: I did some search but it still doesnt work for me.
*see updated question