# JSON format lost in PHP

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3

When I send json data from action script 3 to php using `URLVariables`, the json string changes and cannot be used as json inside php. How to prevent this happening? Or how to fix it?

trace from Flash(send moethod `POST`, variable name `myObject`):

```
[{"data1":"value1","data2":"value2",...},{...},...]
```

`echo $_POST['myObject']` from PHP:

```
[{\"data1\":\"value1\",\"data2\":\"value2\",...},{...},...]
```

`echo json_decode($_POST['myObject'])` from PHP is nothing, when `var_dump(json_decode($_POST['myObject'])`:

```
NULL
```

Comment: Check your error type using  `echo json_last_error();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server automatically escape the `POST` data (As I remember it is an option in `php.ini`). 
To unescape , use `stripslashes` function, and after decode your string ;)

```
 json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myObject']));
```

Based on @therefromhere 's comment, a better solution to set `magic_quotes_gpc` off.
You can do this if you have a root access for the server, or you have permission to set php flags at runtime.
Here is some help for this:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Based on @nl-x 's comment if you want to solve this problem, undepended from your server configuration:

```
$myObject = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? //Examine: is magic quotes gpc on?
               stripslashes($_POST['myObject']) : //if true: unescape the string
               $_POST['myObject'];                //if false, do nothing
json_decode($myObject);
//When php 5.3 or earlier installed on server
```

Comment: That's pretty much it :) If this doesn't work, you have a malformed JSON.

Comment: Better, set magic_quotes_gpc = 0 if you can, it's deprecated in 5.3 and removed in 5.4 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php)

Comment: You saved my day! :) Removing slashes with stripslashes did the job!
+ I did have malformed JSON due to some class malfunction...
I've changed JSON.stringify to com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode PS: I'm using PHP 5.2.17 server

Comment: Do it like this, so even if you change your php.ini or move the code to another server, it will keep working: `$myObject = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($_POST['myObject']) : $_POST['myObject']; json_decode($myObject);`